# How to use macros?

Tags: c, function, macros

Why the answer is a=71? Why doesn't at the end of running this program the answer would be according to: m1(3,2,1)=7 ....a=m2(7,21,14)=7*21+14

```
#define m1(a,b,c) a*b+c
#define m2(x) m1( (x), (x*3), (x*2))

int main()
{
   int a;
   a=m2(m1(3,2,1));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do people abuse macros?

Comment: Please just use functions. If they're this small, they're probably inlined anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you compile with `-E` flag (which runs the preprocessor only, you get:

```
int main()
{
   int a;
   a=(3*2 +1)*(3*2 +1*3)+(3*2 +1*2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And to fix it (i.e., get the result you expected), just rearrange the parentheses on `m2` to `m1(x, (x) * 3, (x) * 2)`. See [here](http://ideone.com/C7IAbD)

Comment: @user The macros don't act like true functions. The preprocessor just does a straight text replacement.

Comment: You can just preprocess by hand: `m2(m1(3,2,1))` is replaced by `m1( (m1(3,2,1)), (m1(3,2,1)*3), (m1(3,2,1)*2))`, which resolves to `(m1(3,2,1))* (m1(3,2,1)*3)+ (m1(3,2,1)*2)`, which resolves to `(3*2 +1)*(3*2 +1*3)+(3*2 +1*2)`